# Filtering out None from column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

Let df be a dataframe and assume df["Scores"] is a column of dtype: object.

Some elements of "Scores" have the value None.  I would like to filter out the None values from the Pandas series df["Scores].

I tried using the boolean series

```
df["Scores"] != None
```

however this returns True everywhere so did not help.

On the other hand the following will extract the values that are not None.

```
vals = []

for x in df["Scores"]:
    if x!= None:
        vals.append(x)
```

Would like to know why the first does not work.

Comment: Does `df.dropna()` work?

Comment: That does seem to work!  Thanks very much!